# Специальные символы в именованиях переменных

Tags: javascript, typescript

Начал изучать javascript и не могу найти руководства по правильному неймингу переменных в этом языке. Как я понимаю никакого жесткого правила нет, однако существуют устные договоренности, на вроде `_variable` это приватная переменная.

Основной вопрос чем характеризуются переменные со знаком $ на конце вида `variable$` и есть ли какой то мануал где можно ознакомиться со всеми договоренностями.

Comment: _Основной вопрос чем характеризуются переменные со знаком $ на конце_ - где ты такое увидел?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase - это предпочтительно

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case

если переходили с PHP - старайтесь не добавлять в начале $ .

А вообще - всё зависит от спецификаций кода. Советую при разработке на фреймворках использовать eslint, ставить правила от какой-нибудь крупной компании (airbnb, google) и будет вам счастье.

Comment: в некоторых командах в переменные вида variable$ сохраняют объект observable (специальный объект библиотеки rxjs, не забивайте пока голову)

Comment: @muturgan спасибо, понятно. Оформите как ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в некоторых командах принято в переменные вида variable$ сохранять объект observable (специальный объект библиотеки rxjs, которая очень активно используется во фреймворке Angular, но в принципе может использоваться где угодно).

Comment: не в "некоторых командах", это финская нотация от Бена Леша (архитектора cycle.js и rxjs)

Comment: @overthesanity ну ведь не все команды этого придерживаются)) (например наша). не знал, спасибо за уточнение!